# My mac keeps panicking

Tags: macos, kernel-panic

Recently my mac has started panicking and I don't really understand why.
The reason for the panics aren't always the same either.

Sometimes the reason for the panic is the same but the thread is different.

All the panics so far are in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Thermatix/a53aeb24b50abea5f8fbb4ae45c0c16f) (which as of posting only contains the most recent one).

The only thing I can pretty much say is I doubt it's Avira as I installed it right at the beginning and this issue is a recent one; I mention this because I read that sometimes kernel extensions can cause panics and Avira has a Kernel extension.

It happens whether I'm in the browser (Chrome) or my terminal (iTerm2).

I have 3 spaces open, 2 browsers and one terminal.

I'm running Tmux in my shell for multiplexing.

One last thing, unrelated, but why do some of the panics error with Bash? I switched my shell to Zsh.

Comment: This is likely to be hardware so run Apple diagnostic

Answer (score 1):

> The only thing I can pretty much say is I doubt it's Avira as I
>   installed it right at the beginning and this issue is a recent one

That could be evidence to the contrary - even a minor OS X upgrade can cause a third party kext to become deprecated, [resulting in persistent panics.](http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/kernelpanics.html)

Unless you completely uninstall the software, you won’t be able to rule it out. [A quick google search of Apple Support Communities](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=avira%20kernel%20panic&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=avira%20kernel%20panic%20site:discussions.apple.com) shows a multitude of panics related to Akira’s drivers.

Another alternative would be to unload the kernel extension temporarily* and test. Open Terminal and enter the following command (replacing with the actual name of the kext):

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/thirdpartykext.kext
```

Confirm it’s unloaded:

```
kextstat | grep com.avira.kext.FileAccessControl
```

`grep` should return nothing. Proceed to reboot your machine.

If you’re unable to recreate the panic, then you’ve isolated the issue. Contact the developers of the software, report it, and wait for them to roll out an update.

---

*To reload the kext, you’d run:

```
sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/thirdpartykext.kext
```